# Automatically populate a field in a form

Tags: javascript

I have a page with 30 photos on it. When a photo is clicked it opens up a form. The first field in the form is "photo name".

How can I automatically have that particular photo's name populate the first field? And so on for the remaining photos.

**UPDATE:**

The photo's name will be the file name. For example, for "28252896.png" it would look like this:

```
<div class="lbm-column width-33">
    <p>
        <img src="Images/Screenshots/Tennis/28252896.png" width="300" height="199" class="scalable" alt="">
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: hi friend, first you have set or get the name when you load all photos , can be use something atribute and when clicked in this point you send the name

Comment: Please show us some code. Its very hard to help you with the given information

Comment: Will the photo's name just be the file name?  Or some derivative of the file name?

Comment: Yes it will be the photos file name  - in this instance, 28252896.png,         <div class="lbm-column width-33"><p><img src="Images/Screenshots/Tennis/28252896.png" width="300" height="199" class="scalable" alt=""></p></div>

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Where is the form on the HTML page in relation to the `img`/`div`?  It's best just to provide your HTML so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: the form is on a different html page than the image, Click the upper left photo on this page - http://www.personalizedclubmarketing.com/golf.html and it will open this page - http://www.personalizedclubmarketing.com/form2.html -which is where I want to populate the first field

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to give your link a url parameter.

For example:

```
<div class="lbm-column width-33">
  <p><a target="new" href="form2.html?name=10205157_m.png"><img src="Images/Screenshots/Golf/10205157_m.png" width="300" height="200" class="scalable" alt=""></a></p>
</div>
```

It's the same as on your page, except with `?name=10205157_m.png` at the end of the href.

Your form on the destination page might look a bit like this:

```
<form class="" action="#" method="post">
  <label>Photo name <input id="photoName" type="text" name="..." value=""></label>
  ...
</form>
```

Then have some JavaScript (function from [this page](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var photoNameField = document.getElementById('photoName');
var photoName = GetURLParameter("name");
if (photoName){
  photoNameField.value = photoName;
}

function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
  var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
  {
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam){
      return sParameterName[1];
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This gets the value of the `name` parameter from the url and changes the value of the input field to match.